# Is elementary a Good Choice for a Corporate Setting?

Tags: settings, system, networking, security

Would elementary os be a good choice of Linux distros for a corporate setting? I'm just curious.

Comment: What corporate settings mean? I doubt it is a good choice if you want to manage end points. The standard way is to use Windows 10, Global Policy Objects (is there a Linux replacement which allows to restrict settings like ACL and user settings globally?) , Active Directory which in case of Linux can be replaced by LDAP, SCCM which I have no idea does any Linux replacement exist which allows you to manage globally software on Linux machines (SCCM expert opinion needed). And I have no idea does ClamAV has any Management console on Linux. If not then the only choice is some antivirus like Eset.

Comment: It was a question for discussion in school and the company didn't have to be global. However, in class, we discussed using ConfigMgr for older servers, Microsoft Azure Management for newer ones. Others threw out alternatives like Chef, Puppet (of course), Rudder, Ansible. There were a bunch but I really don't remember them all. Sorry I didn't see this until now.

Comment: Ansible or Chef is only for automation, not for managing. Oracle has Satellite which allows to manage servers. Puppet is also for managing servers. I do not care about Windows Servers, because I am Linux sysadmin.